# SIP plugin for Trillian

Tags: plugins, instant-messaging, sip, trillian

I like using Trillian for chats (Skype, Google Talk, ...) but I cannot add a SIP Account to make calls with Trillian directly.

Google always tells me to download the [SIP Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trilliansip/) for Trillian, **but this is NOT A SIP Plugin**, it is a plugin for the Microsoft Lync Server (OCS).

**Does someone has a plugin or is already using [SIP](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) within Trillian?** Or is Trillian doing something to get SIP in their application, because this is a long-requested feature. Or is there an alternative to Trillian supporting SIP?

Comment: I guess Pidgin supports SIP -- wish Trillian did though.